# Apache Pig convert rows to a single column delimited with character

Tags: apache-pig

I need convert Value columns to a single row grouped by the City and delimited with the "|" (pipe) character

> DATA = LOAD '/tmp/test.dat' Using PigStorage(',') as (
>         CITY:chararray,
>         VALUE:chararray
>   )

**Input:(City/Value)**

ISTANBUL,1

ISTANBUL,2

ISTANBUL,3

NEWYORK,8

NEWYORK,9

**Output:**

ISTANBUL,1|2|3

NEWYORK,8|9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do a group by on `CITY`, then use BagToString (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/func.html#bagtostring) to convert the values for each group into the required string representation. Something like (untested!)

```
data = LOAD '/tmp/test.dat' using PigStorage(',') AS (city:chararray, value:chararray);
data_grp = GROUP data BY city;
result = FOREACH data_grp GENERATE group AS city, BagToString(data.value, '|') AS values;
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you.